# Form Validation with jQuery - Weird Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Alright, so I'm trying to do form validation with jQuery. Not sure why but when you click submit it redirects you to the page you're at already.

The forms action is blank and I included the javascript file in the header.

I will put the code below. Let me know if you see whats wrong. I want it to validate with jQuery then send you to a php file with those values in the method POST.

Register.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name=regsubmit]').click(function(){
    var fname = $('input[name=regfirstname');
    var lname = $('input[name=reglastnaame');
    var email = $('input[name=regemail');
    var password = $('input[name=regpassword');
    var repeatpassword = $('input[name=regrepeatpassword');
    var username = $('input[name=regusername');
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.indexOf(".");
    if (fname==null || fname=="")
      {
      alert('First name must be filled out!');
      return false;
      }
    if (lname==null || lname=="")
      {
      alert('Last name must be filled out!');
      return false;
      }
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length)
      {
      alert('Not a valid e-mail address!');
      return false;
      }
    if (username==null || username=="")
      {
      alert("Username field must be filled out!");
      return false;
      }
    if (password==null || password=="")
      {
      alert("Subject field must be filled out!");
      return false;
      }
     if (repeatpassword==null || repeatpassword=="")
      {
      alert("Repeat password field must be filled out!");
      return false;
      }
    if (password != repeatpassword)
      {
      alert("The passwords do not match!");
      return false;
      }
    else
    {
    location.href="register.php";
    }
  });
});
```

Form:

```
               <form name="register" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-container row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6"> 

                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="regfirstname">First Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input id="regfirstname" tabindex="1" name="regfirstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="input-large" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="regusername">Username</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input id="regusername" tabindex="3" name="regusername" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="input-large" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>



                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="regpassword">Password</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input id="regpassword" tabindex="5" name="regpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-large">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                          <div class="controls">
                            <button id="regsubmit" tabindex="7" name="regsubmit" class="button background-asbestos">Submit</button>
                          </div>
                    </div><!-- .span6 -->

                    <div class="span6"> 

                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="reglastname">Lastname</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input id="reglastname" tabindex="2" name="reglastname" type="text" placeholder="Lastname" class="input-large" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="regemail">Email</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input id="regemail" name="regemail" tabindex="4" type="text" placeholder="example@example.com" class="input-large"</td>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="regrepeatpassword">Repeat Password</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input id="regrepeatpassword" tabindex="6" name="regrepeatpassword" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="input-large" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- .span6 -->
                    <!-- span6 --> 
                  </div><!-- .row-fluid -->
                </fieldset>
              </form>
```

Comment: if form action is blank, the default behavior is to "submit" to the same page you are on => http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action

Comment: So what do I set the action to? register.js ?

Comment: what are you submitting the form TO? what page is processing the information to send to a server somewhere?

Comment: The php file but in my javascript file it also redirects to that page. Also in my javascript file it checks when you click that submit button then it checks the fields for validation and if they're all good then it moves you on to register.php.

Answer (score 1):

Alright your JS and HTML is a big mess of stuff, so I won't recreate it all, but basics:

Give your form an ID:

```
<form id="SomeForm" name="register" method="POST">
```

Then prevent default action, and submit if passes:

```
// reference the button by the ID you gave it
$('#regsubmit').click(function(e){
    // stop original submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // all your checking stuff here, but if true, then:
    document.getElementById('SomeForm').submit();
});
```

This ensures that you are referencing the button correctly, preventing submission correctly, and submitting only if valid.

Comment: Do I then add an action to it? Or keep it like that because where does it redirect to register.php? Because when I add it like that, it still just refreshes page.

Comment: You do need to add the action as the register.js page

Comment: Then how does it redirect to register.php? I tried it with register.js and it just redirects to register.js which shows the code for the script.

Comment: you need to specify register.php in the action, i.e. `action="register.php"`. this, combined with my mentioned changes, will validate and submit appropriately.

Comment: Not working, its sending me straight to register.php, not sure why

Comment: did you include jQuery, include the `e` in the click component, and include `e.preventDefault()`? try commenting out the submit line i provided. if it is still sending at all ... you aren't doing one of those three things.

Answer (score 0):

prevent default action on submit

```
$('button[name=regsubmit]').click(function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();

 //your code below    

}
```